# Python : Get value from a list of Json dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, google-api

I need to get values from google api response.
I have json response as follows:

```
direct =
[{ 
'summary': 'Jakarta Inner Ring Road/Jl. Pantura/Jl. Tol Pelabuhan', 
'legs': [{
          'duration': {'value': 2130, 'text': '36 mins'}, 
          'via_waypoint': [], 
          'start_address': 'North Jakarta, North Jakarta City, Special Capital Region of Jakarta, Indonesia', 
          'duration_in_traffic': {'value': 2475, 'text': '41 mins'}, 
          'end_address': 'West Jakarta, West Jakarta City, Special Capital Region of Jakarta, Indonesia', 
          'start_location': {'lat': -6.138709899999999, 'lng': 106.8640136}, 
          'distance': {'value': 17777, 'text': '17.8 km'}, 
          'traffic_speed_entry': [], 
          'end_location': {'lat': -6.168346199999999, 'lng': 106.7588346}
         }]
}]
```

I need to get the `value` of `duration` and `distance` from `legs`

I've tried several ways, this is my last code:

```
for who in direct:
    act_dist = (direct ["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"])
    act_time2 = (direct2 ["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"])
```

and get this error:
*Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:src/distance.py", line 34, in <module>
    act_dist = (direct ["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*
```

Can anyone help with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `direct` is a `List`. You can't use Strings to access its Elements

Comment: `direct[0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"]` should work. Specify index on `direct` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should actually be:

```
for who in direct:
    act_dist = (who ["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"])
    act_time2 = (who ["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in direct:
    for l in d['legs']:
        print l['duration']
        print l['distance']
```

You need to traverse all lists.